# c++ Multiple key/value pairs for one and the same key

Tags: c++, arrays, key-value

What different options do I have in c++, if I want something like this?

```
array = [];
array[] = ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'roger'];
array[] = ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'clark'];
```

I've been looking around, and I did found `map`, but it does not seem to work with multiple key/values for one and the same key/index.

Comment: Perhaps a `std::map` with a key and a container of values?

Comment: So you want a data structure that can contain same keys, or for each key you want it to map to multiple values?

Comment: [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is good. Thanks alot mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple choices that might meet your requirements:

1. If you simply want a data structure that maintains a mapping, you could either use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.
2. If you want a data structure that can maintain a mapping with same keys, then you may want to use `std::multimap`.
3. If you want a data structure that maintains a mapping which can map a single key to multiple values, you can set your value a `std::vector`,  `std::set`, `std::unordered_set` or any other containers, depends on your need. For example, it could be `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a vector (or array) of `std::pair` values. It's not exactly key/value, but it allows you to have pairs with common "keys".